# Laravel request helper in URL to get ID / Resource ID

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-middleware, laravel-request

I'm working on a Laravel 5.6 app and have the following two API routes:

```
Route::resource('/partners', 'API\Partners\PartnersController');

Route::resource('/partners/{id}/sales-team', 'API\Partners\SalesTeamController');
```

In both of the controllers I am referencing a custom middleware 'VerifyUserOwnsTeam' in the construct method.

To get the resource ID from the request in the middleware I previously had:

```
$request->route('partner')
```

This worked a URL such as:

```
/api/partners/1
```

However, I am now calling a new end point such as:

```
/api/partners/1/sales-team
```

In my middleware the request route param for partner is null. If I change the reference to be:

```
$request->route('id')
```

Then it works for the latter endpoint, but fails on the first for a null value.

Any idea how to get this consistent?

Answer (score 1):

I use laravel 8 and got solved in my case.
I have put the param **id** from the router to function in my controller. Then passing the **id** with compact function to use on my view.

Here's the code example

My router:

```
Route::resource('stock/{id}', StockController::class);
```

My controller:

```
public function index($id, Request $request)
{
    return View::make("pages.stock.index", compact('id'));
}
```

My view:

```
{{$id}}
```

Idk this is works or not for your case, but I hope you get some clue.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>you need to change your first route to accept an id:</strike>

```
Route::resource('/partners/{id?}', 'API\Partners\PartnersController');
```

Comment: The resource route already sets the id as an accepted parameter.

Comment: yeah sorry about that, just noticed it's a resource route

Comment: can't you name your route param to `partner`? `Route::resource('/partners/{partner}/sales-team', 'API\Partners\SalesTeamController');`

Comment: Hey nice idea, I tried it a few mins ago too but didn't work. Gave it another go and what d'ya know! Worked like a charm, cheers either way :)

Answer (score -1):

For all searchers:
For resources in edit/update/delete actions you can access id of the model inside Request classes using

```
$this->get('id')
```